# Deep Search with relationships eloquent models

Tags: php, laravel, recursion, eloquent, recursive-query

I'm trying to build a dynamic search by searching a model and specific columns in it's relationships and nested relationship. So far this is the code i've come up with

The class I created has a `queryFields` constant which holds all the fields  of the base model (`Client`) to be searched. Any array in this constant is a relationship with its corresponding searchable fields. and so on.

The `queryWhereBuilder` method is supposed to search recursively through all these fields but i can't get it to work properly. It thinks the nested relationships are relationships of the base model.

I'd like to know if this is the ideal way to do this or if there's a better way.

```
class SearchBuilder {    
    const CC = Client::class;
    const queryFields = [
        'id',
        'name',
        'phone',
        'email',
        'address',
        'details'=>[
            'former_id'
        ],
        'invoices'=>[
            'reference',
            'receipts'=>[
                'description',
                'reference'
            ]
        ]
    ];

    protected $builder;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->builder =  (static::CC)::query();
    }

    protected function queryWhereBuilder($search, $fields = null, $builder = null, $whereHas = false)
    {
        $builder = $builder ?: $this->builder;
        $fields = $fields ?: static::queryFields;
        foreach ($fields as $field => $value) {
            if (!$whereHas) {
                if (!is_array($value) && $field === 0){
                    $builder = $builder->where($value, 'like', "%".$search."%");
                }
                elseif(is_array($value)){
                    $builder = $this->queryWhereBuilder($search, $value, $builder, $field);
                }
                else{
                    $builder = $builder->orWhere($value, 'like', "%".$search."%");
                }
            }
            else{
                if (!is_array($value) && $field === 0) {
                    $builder = $builder->whereHas($whereHas, function($query) use ($search,$value){
                        $query->where($value, 'like', "%".$search."%");
                    });
                } elseif(is_array($value)) {

                    $builder = $this->queryWhereBuilder($search, $value, $builder, $field);
                }
                else{
                    $builder = $builder->orWhereHas($whereHas, function($query) use ($search,$value){
                        $query->orWhere($value, 'like', "%".$search."%");
                    });
                }               
            }
        }
        return $builder;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `$whereHas` parameter should be constructed to be dot delimited. For example in the first recursion you need to send `invoices` but in the second level it needs to be `invoices.receipts`

Comment: @apokryfos thanks a lot. That helped!. I have been on this for hours.